# Редактирование многострочной команды MySQL

Tags: mysql, терминал

Копирую чужую команду для MySQL в терминал, состоит из нескольких строк. Как мне переместиться на верхние строки и редактировать их?

Comment: возможно стрелкой влево долго мотать. или отредактировать заранее в любом текстовом редакторе

Comment: А клавиши курсора не работают?

Comment: Клавиши курсора вверх и вниз не перемещают курсор, а меняют команду на предыдущую. Стрелка влево - упирается в начало последней строки.

А еще я использую клиент Putty для работы с сервером, здесь ведь точная копия терминала?